# How do I replace a string without using the replace function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a javascript program where I replace all spaces in a string with %20 without using the replace function. I'm getting an error when I try to run my program. Not sure what's wrong.

```js
let urlEncode = function(text) {
  text = text.trim();
  let newstring;
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == " ") {
      newstring[i] = "%20";
    } else {
      newstring[i] = text[i];
    }
  }
  return newstring;
};

console.log(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure"));
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable - you can't assign to their indicies. Rather, initialize `newstring` to the empty string, use `+=` to concatenate the existing string with the new character(s):

```js
let urlEncode = function(text) {
  text = text.trim();
  let newstring = '';
  for (const char of text) {
    newstring += char === ' '? '%20' : char;
  }
  return newstring;
};

console.log(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure"));
```

Or, don't reinvent the wheel, and use `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("blue is greener than purple for sure"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use combination of `split` and `join` to achieve in simplified way.

```js
let urlEncode = function(text) {
  return text
    .trim()
    .split(" ")
    .join("%20");
};

console.log(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Error Is first you must set `newstring` in first 
`let` only create your variable but not assign any value to it then `newstring[0]` is `undefined` then you get error 
i use `+=` for add char to string and it is better
you can change your Code Like this

```js
   let urlEncode = function(text) {
  text = text.trim();
  let newstring=""; 
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == " ") {
      newstring+= "%20";
    } else {
      newstring+= text[i];
    }
  }
return newstring;
};

console.log(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure"));
```